# <label> tag and input not going to new line

Tags: css

I am seeing an example where the author has written something like this:

```
 <p>
  <label>Team Name</label>
  <input type="text">
 </p>
```

The results he had is a label saying : Team Name and below that in an input of type  text. For me when I am trying the same example, I am seeing them all on the same line. Both of us are referencing AngularJS, Bootstrap.css.

Any idea why? P.S: Still new to CSS and all front end development things.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4ovg3pz8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

label and input elements are inline element and to force them go below use `display: block;`

```
p input{
  display: block;
}
```